# Matching patterns on Azure rules engine for redirects

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

We are migrating from netlify to azure and I need to recreate some redirects, for example:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "https://www.aaa.jp/ja-jp/*"
  to = "https://www.aaa.com/ja-jp/:splat"
  status = 302
  force = true
```

I tried with Azure CDN and the default Microsoft tier, but didn't have much luck because after searching the docs, I still have no idea how to match patterns (like * and :splat above).

Answer (score -1):

You can write redirect rules in your web.config file if you are using Azure App Service app running on windows as discussed in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madhurabharadwaj/2018/06/01/azure-app-services-understanding-url-re-write/).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://<<appdomain>>/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>              
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is not what he was asking about. He was looking for a solution around Microsoft Standard Rules Engine.